# Append icon to date string format in listView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I can't figure out how to add an icon from a imagelist to the input event.

Here is the button code:

```
string date = string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm}", DateTime.Now);
listView1.Items.Add(date);
```

I have tried many versions of this line `listView1.Items[0].ImageIndex = 0;` inside, but no succes.

Can you help?
Thanks.

Comment: have you set listview1 imagelist? like `listView1.SmallImageList = YourImageList`

Comment: Tried that, didn't help. But problem is solved now. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to begin by ensure you have set `ListView.View` Property to either `View.SmallIcon` or `View.LargeIcon`

```
listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.SmallIcon; // or LargeIcon
```

Depending on the `ListView.View`, you need to then assign the `ImageList` to `ListView.SmallImageList` or `ListView.LargeImageList`;

```
 listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;
```

Now you could assign the index as the following.

```
string date = string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm}", DateTime.Now);
listView1.Items.Add(date,0);
```